# Dependencyproperty strange behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I've created my usercontrol with a dependencyproperty.
I noted that if the dependency property has the same name regitered of property, when I insert the control inside in a windows and write via xaml code the value , this control not show the labels, I need insert in codebehind the value and when start the application the control show the labels.

If I change the registered name of dependancypropety the controll Show the labels without pass the value via code behind, and show the lable each time I modify the value via xaml or via codebehind.

this is my usercontrol.
xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Controls.MyUserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid x:Name="GridRoot">

</Grid>
```

and this is code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace My.Controls
{
   /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Plate.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Point pointOfOrigin;
    private Double labelsRad;
    //private Byte numOfChucks;
    private List<Label> labelNumber = new List<Label>();
    private List<Canvas> label = new List<Canvas>();

    #region - Dependency Properties mandatory for Binding -
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumOfLabelsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NumOfLabels", typeof(byte), typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(byte.MinValue));
    #endregion - Dependency Properties for Binding -

   [DefaultValue(byte.MinValue)]
    public byte NumOfLabels
    {
        get { return (byte)GetValue(MyUserControl1.NumOfLabelsProperty); }
        set
        {
            if (this.NumOfLabels != value)
            {
                SetValue(MyUserControl1.NumOfLabelsProperty, value);
                LabelsRender();
                OnPropertyChanged("NumOfLabels");
            }
        }
    }

    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        //just to show when the control is designer mode
        pointOfOrigin = new Point(this.ActualWidth / 2, this.ActualHeight / 2);
        labelsRad = this.Width / 2;
    }

    private void PosLabels()
    {
        var indexLabel = Byte.MinValue;
        var pointLabel = new Point();

        for (; indexLabel < this.NumOfLabels; indexLabel++)
        {
            pointLabel = new Point((this.ActualWidth + (indexLabel * 50) )/2,(this.ActualHeight + (indexLabel *50))/2) ;
            Canvas.SetLeft(labelNumber[indexLabel], pointLabel.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(labelNumber[indexLabel], pointLabel.Y);
        }
    }
    private void RemoveLabels()
    {
        var indexLabel = Byte.MinValue;

        for (; indexLabel < labelNumber.Count; indexLabel++)
        {
            this.label[indexLabel].Children.Remove(labelNumber[indexLabel]);

            this.GridRoot.Children.Remove(label[indexLabel]);
        }

        //clean up 
        labelNumber.Clear();
        labelNumber.Clear();
        GC.Collect();
    }
    private void AddLabels()
    {
        var indexLabel = Byte.MinValue;

        for (; indexLabel < this.NumOfLabels; indexLabel++)
        {
            labelNumber.Add(
               new Label()
               {
                   Content = (indexLabel + 1).ToString("D2"),
                   Height = 23,
                   Width = 23,
                   Name = "labelNumber" + indexLabel,

               });
            label.Add(
                new Canvas()
                {
                    Name = "Label" + indexLabel,
                    Height = 23,
                    Width = 23,
                });

            label[indexLabel].Children.Add(labelNumber[indexLabel]);
            this.GridRoot.Children.Add(label[indexLabel]);

        }
    }

    private void LabelsRender()
    {
        RemoveLabels();
        AddLabels();
        PosLabels();
    }
    #region - INotifyPropertyChanged implementation -
    // Basically, the UI thread subscribes to this event and update the binding if the received Property Name correspond to the Binding Path element
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion - INotifyPropertyChanged implementation -
}
```

this is the windowtest
xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Controls.MyUserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid x:Name="GridRoot">

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

this is codeBehind:

```
enter cousing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace XTesting
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for WindowTest.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class WindowTest : Window
{
    public WindowTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MyUserControl.NumOfLabels = 7;
    }
}
}
```

if you want to try please delete the line after Initialize component and change de property dependency name in this form

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NumOfLabelsProperty=DependencyProperty.Register("NumOfLabelsP",typeof(byte),typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(byte.MinValue));
```

Answer (score 2):

> and write via xaml code the value , this control not show the labels, I need insert in codebehind the value

This is the correct, documented behaviour.

Your `public byte NumOfLabels { get ... set ... }` property is ony the 'front door' for code behind, the databindings won't use it.

Find another solution for the logic in `set { }`. You can add callbacks in the Register method for that.

And please, don't use `byte` here. It's a number, use `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `NumOfLabels` property should be declared like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NumOfLabelsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "NumOfLabels", typeof(int), typeof(MyUserControl1),
        new PropertyMetadata(0, NumOfLabelsPropertyChanged));

public int NumOfLabels
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(NumOfLabelsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NumOfLabelsProperty, value); }
}

private static void NumOfLabelsPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MyUserControl1)obj).LabelsRender();
}
```

Note that you should not call anything else than `GetValue` and `SetValue` in the CLR wrapper of a dependency property, as explained in [Checklist for Defining a Dependency Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.100).aspx#checklist):

> **Implementing the "Wrapper"**
>
> ... In all but exceptional circumstances, your wrapper implementations should perform only the
>   GetValue and SetValue actions, respectively. The reason for this is
>   discussed in the topic [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.100).aspx).

You'll have to register a `PropertyChangedCallback` to react on property value changes.

Besides that it is not necessary to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for dependency properties, because they implement their own change notification mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

your xaml is bad. In fact the GridRoot used in your windows is different from the one used in your userControl. For a better behavior, your need to insert you usercontrol in a new windows and then set your property. your xaml should look something like this

```
<x:Windows>
   <local :MyUserControl1 NumOfLabels = 7/>
</x:Windows>
```